# Date and Date format Calculation Android

Tags: android, date, datetime, date-format

I have a function with date calculations. It compares the database from and to date which I already retrieved, with the input from and to date which I am passing. While debugging, it showing wrong dates after assignment inside the for loop.(input and database dates) Below I shown the example with a image.

Function code:

```
/*String[] veh - vehicle name, String[] from - table from date array,
 * String[] to - table to date array,String from1 - input from date, String to1 - input to date*/
private List getDateComparison(String[] veh, String[] from, String[] to,String from1, String to1) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM",Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date table_from,table_to,input_from,input_to;
    long diff=0,diff1=0,diff2=0,diff3=0;
    int count=0,county=0;;

    for(int i=0;i<veh.length;i++){
        table_from=df.parse(from[i]);
        table_to=df.parse(to[i]);
        input_from=df.parse(from1);
        input_to=df.parse(to1);
        table_from=df.parse(df.format(table_from));
        table_to=df.parse(df.format(table_to));
        input_from=df.parse(df.format(input_from));
        input_to=df.parse(df.format(input_to));
        diff=table_from.getTime()-input_from.getTime();
        diff1=table_from.getTime()-input_to.getTime();
        diff2=input_from.getTime()-table_to.getTime();
        diff3=input_to.getTime()-table_to.getTime();
        if((diff > 0 && diff1>0) || (diff2 > 0 && diff3>0)){
            count++;
            removeAndAddList(veh[i],1);
            Log.d("Date", " ok with from");
        }
        else {
            county = 100;
            removeAndAddList(veh[i],2);
        }
    }
    return vehic;//= veh[0];
}
```

Function Screenshot while Debugging:

[image]

**Edited:**

Before I used the date format as,

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

At that time the calculation worked perfectly. Now it was making some issues with the date format. I think my dateformat is doing something wrong inside the for loop. It was showing bigger dates after assigning the dates with dateformat. Where I did wrong?

Comment: please give us some more context. how is the data set and gathered in the application ? What do you want to achieve ? I think your code may not be the right way to do it, so that is why I ask, so maybe we can steer you in a better direction.

Comment: Thank you @Grease. I don't want to change the entire code. It will take more time to modify. More dependency is there. I am giving one input from and to date, then array of from and to date from table. The values are changing after the assignment inside the for loop. I think the dateformat is something doing wrong.

Comment: not sure if it makes the problem but the format you are using for the `SDF` is not correct `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM",Locale.ENGLISH);` as **M means Month in year** and you are using it as minutes? change to `mm` **HH:mm** and give it a try

Comment: @Yazan, Thank you so much. It worked.

Comment: good to hear that, if you want i can post it as answer, with a suggestion to use in your code instead of the `diff` approach to compare dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you are using for the SDF is not correct

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

as **M** means *Month in year* and you are using it as minutes.

change to `HH:mm`
`... = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",Locale.ENGLISH);`

***off-topic:***
instead of using `diff=table_from.getTime()-input_from.getTime();` you can make use of `after()` and `before()` methods for `Date`

you can compare dates as following (from your code):

```
if((diff > 0 && diff1>0) || (diff2 > 0 && diff3>0)){
```

will be:

```
if((table_from.after(input_from) && table_from.after(input_to)) 
|| (input_from.after(table_to) && input_to.after(table_to))){
```

*now you can remove all the `getTime()` subtraction lines from the code (the 4 lines)*

Comment: Thank you @Yazan. It is very helpful. Is my question understandable? I got few down votes.

Comment: @AbishR the question is well formatted and you tried hard to explain your problem, though maybe it was better to focus on the date value to be incorrect instead of using `date calculation` in the title and you could highlighted or (bold)  some words to make it clear, like "the database **from** and **to** date which I already..." otherwise you have good effort there :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.